# rvest - find html-node with last page number

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm learning web scraping and created a little exercise for myself to scrape all titles of a recipe site: https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=1. (I got inspired by this post: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/web-scraping-r-online-food-blogs.html).

*I want to scrape the value of the last page number, which is (at time of writing) number 64*. You can find the number of pages at the bottom. I see that this is stored as "a.facetwp-page last", but for some reason cannot access this node. I can see that the page number values are stored as 'data-page', but I'm unable to get this value through 'html_attrs'.

I believe the parent node is "div.facetwp-pager" and I can access that one as follows:

```
library(rvest)
pg <- read_html("https://pinchofyum.com/recipes")
html_nodes(pg, "div.facetwp-pager")
```

But this is as far as I get. I guess I'm missing something small, but cannot figure out what it is. I know about Rselenium, but I would like to know if and how to get that last page value (64) with rvest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes scraping with rvest doesn't work, especially when the webpage is dynamically generated with java script (I also wasn't able to scrape this info with `rvest`). In those cases, you can use the `RSelenium` package. I was able to scrape your desired element like this:

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox")) #specify browser type you want Selenium to open
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("https://pinchofyum.com/recipes?fwp_paged=1") # navigates to webpage

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", ".last") #find desired element

txt <- webElem$getElementText() # gets us the HTML

#> txt
#>[[1]]
#>[1] "64"
```